# Where is the Google Search Bar in Unity?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook, lenses

On many Screenshots from Unity I can see a Google Search Bar in the upper panel, like in this Screenshot

http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/10/shuttleworth-unity-shell-will-be-default-desktop-in-ubuntu-1104.ars

Is this a newer version of Unity? And if it's newer, where can I get this version?

Comment: please mark this question as answered ^^

Comment: sorry, I'm still learning. done :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That screenshot is out of date. Current Unity as it ships in 10.10 does not have a text field in the top panel. Search will be implemented in what we call [Lenses](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses).

Comment: Ok, so that screenshot is an older version. thx

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess those were mockups, and the design changed later. You do get a search bar when you click the files or apps launcher, and if your search returns no results you get a "search the web" button which opens a Google search with the terms you wrote.

Comment: There actually was a time where that Google search was hooked up - certainly the (quite unstable) version unveiled at the Maverick UDS  six months ago had it.  It dropped out pretty early.